# Generic class factory in Python

Tags: python, oop, python-3.x

Consider a class with the following structure:

```
class Foo(object):
    # ...
    class Meta:
        goo = 1
```

If I take `Foo` I'll have `Foo.Meta.goo == 1`. What's the right way to create an abstract class factory `foo_factory` such that I can call:

```
>>> Clazz = foo_factory(goo=2)
>>> Clazz
<class '__main__.Foo'>
>>> Clazz.Meta.goo
2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use assignment:

```
def foo_factory(goo):
    class Foo(object):
        class Meta:
            pass
    Foo.Meta.goo = goo
    return Foo
```

I created the classes as a nested structure; you could use `type()` calls but I find the above to be more readable.

Or you could use a different name for the closure:

```
def foo_factory(goo):
    goo_value = goo  # provide a closure with a non-conflicting name
    class Foo(object):
        class Meta:
            goo = goo_value
    return Foo
```

Either way, the classes produced are created anew (they are not shared between calls).

Comment: This solution has one drawback regarding finding errors: All of the instances of Foo and Meta will have the same class name.

Comment: ... to illustrate this poine: MyClass1 = foo_factory('spam'); MyClass2 = foo_factory(2) will produce different classes with identical names: x=MyClass1(); y=MyClass2(); isinstance(x,MyClass2) == False; type(x) != type(y) but when you try type(x) and type(y) in the console, you get the same answer: <class '__main__.Foo'>

Comment: @Malte: To combine the readability of the `class` statement with the ability to generate a new name each time via `type()` you could just create a subclass for the name with  `return type(generated_name, (Foo,), {})`.

Answer (score 0):

I'll trust you based on your points. My normal answer would be "OMG WHY?????" ;)

```
def foo_factory(goo):
    return type('Foo', (), {
        'Meta': type('Meta', (), {"goo": goo})
        })
```

Comment: Why? Probably because they are producing dynamic Django models or forms.

Comment: Django models support inner classes? I didn't expect that. Thanks! (ah, it's actually the Meta inner class, not inner model, I see now)